# Commandlink ajax not working inside of header facet inside of primefaces datatable

Tags: jsf, primefaces

So in the following code the ajax inside the header facet does not call the backing bean (but it seems to call the execute and render I think) but the link outside the datatable works perfectly fine does anyone have any Idea why?

```
    <h:commandLink value="Types"  >
            <f:ajax listener="#{typeBean.sortTypeList()}" execute="@this" render="@this"/>
      </h:commandLink>
    <p:dataTable id="fluidTable" widgetVar="fluidTable" var="vehBase" value="#{vehicleBean.currentVehicleBaseSet}" >
            <p:columnGroup type="header"> 
                <p:row>
                    <p:column rowspan="" >
                        <f:facet name="header">  
                            <h:panelGroup>
                                <h:commandLink value="Types" >
                                    <f:ajax listener="#{typeBean.sortTypeList()}" execute="@this" render="@this"/>
                                </h:commandLink>
                            </h:panelGroup>
                        </f:facet> 

                    </p:column>
                </p:row> 
            </p:columnGroup>
```

Comment: I guess it should be  `process="fluidTable" render="fluidTable"`, also make sure your managed bean is at least `@ViewScoped`.

Answer (score -1):

Put data table inside of primefaces panel and instead of h:commandLink use primefaces commandlink or button, if you use primefaces in the page, all components should be in primefaces.